# Problems installing fbprophet on ubuntu 18.04 not working

Tags: python, facebook-prophet

I have a docker image based on ubuntu 18.04, where I am trying to install fbprophet. I installed python3.7 dev, libpcap-dev libpq-dev and build essentials with this command
`RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip libsm6 libxext6 python3.7-dev  build-essential libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libsqlite3-dev libbz2-dev libffi-dev zlib1g-dev libpcap-dev libpq-dev`

I then installed following packages in the following way

```
RUN pip3 install numpy==1.19.5
RUN pip3 install pandas==1.1.5
RUN pip3 install Pillow==8.2.0
RUN pip3 install PyMeeus==0.5.11
RUN pip3 install pyparsing==2.4.7
RUN pip3 install cmdstanpy==0.9.5 Cython==0.29.3 ephem==4.0.0.2 hijri_converter==2.1.3 convertdate==2.3.2 korean_lunar_calendar==0.2.1 lunarcalendar==0.0.9 holidays==0.11.1 cython tqdm==4.61.1 pystan==2.17.1
```

Finally I tried to install fbprohet 0.7.1, but then I get the following error:

`error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 4`
I have tried researching this issue, and the common solution seemed to be to install python3.x-dev, build essentials and libpcap-dev libpq-dev, which I have already.

I am researching this issue for quite some time now, but this error message persists, is there any solution to it?

Edit:
This is the full error message:

````
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-yc4ch36e/fbprophet_6cbb80365f414249ac2d886e0e6a654d/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-yc4ch36e/fbprophet_6cbb80365f414249ac2d886e0e6a654d/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-hv6ghna1
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-yc4ch36e/fbprophet_6cbb80365f414249ac2d886e0e6a654d/
  Complete output (19 lines):
  /usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib
  creating build/lib/fbprophet
  creating build/lib/fbprophet/stan_model
  DIAGNOSTIC(S) FROM PARSER:
  Warning: left-hand side variable (name=cp_idx) occurs on right-hand side of assignment, causing inefficient deep copy to avoid aliasing.
  Warning: left-hand side variable (name=m_pr) occurs on right-hand side of assignment, causing inefficient deep copy to avoid aliasing.
  
  INFO:pystan:COMPILING THE C++ CODE FOR MODEL anon_model_dfdaf2b8ece8a02eb11f050ec701c0ec NOW.
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:367: FutureWarning:
  
  Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: /tmp/tmpwga4ct8b/stanfit4anon_model_dfdaf2b8ece8a02eb11f050ec701c0ec_6094426740594523141.pyx
  
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 4
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fbprophet
```
````

Comment: There is probably more output to show.

Comment: The error you have apparently investigated is the case when `x64_64-linux-gnu-gcc` cannot be run because it wasn't installed. This one is instead an example of it running, but failing for other reasons.

Comment: Tangentially, you almost certainly don't want to create a Python 2 module, but I'm guessing fixing that won't change the outcome for the immediate problem.

Comment: @tripleee you mean using pyhon2-dev?

Comment: No, I mean read the warning about `language_level` being unset and figure out how to properly set that (assuming of course the package supports Python 3 in the first place).

Comment: The language level problem is solved, however the gcc error still remains